# Commenting the contents of a Function, but keeping the call to the function intact. Does the Compiler figure out not to compile the function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my VC++(6.0) project, there is a lot of logging. The logging is done by the function

```
void LogMsg(const char* formatStr, ...)
{
   ....
   ....
}
```

To Since the logging is too extensive, commenting out each line would be very slow.
So I have commented the contents of the function LogMsg.

My question is, is the C++ compiler smart enough to ignore the function and the function call doing compilation or will it compile and I will have an unnecessary jump in the code due to the empty function call?

Comment: You can mark it as `inline` to get sure.

Comment: Just take a look at the assembly.

Comment: VC6 isn't very smart. And that's almost a compliment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be 100% sure, without depending on what the compiler actually does, you should define a macro as follows:

```
#define LogMsg(...)
```

This macro should replace the **declaration** of the LogMsg function, and you can remove the function definition from your code.  If you want to keep the possibility of re-introducing logging at a future date, you can do something of the sort:

In header file **logging.h**

```
#ifdef ENABLE_LOGGING
void LogMsg(const char* formatStr, ...)
#else
#define LogMsg(...)
#endif
```

In source file **logging.cpp**

```
#ifdef ENABLE_LOGGING
void LogMsg(const char* formatStr, ...)
{
    ....
    ....
}
#endif
```

Then, you will enable or disable logging by defining or not defining `ENABLE_LOGGING` in your project's preprocessor definitions.

Comment: This has the additional benefit of also eliminating any temporaries. E.g. disabling `LogMsg(ToUppercase(FooStr))` will eliminate the temporary uppercased string.

Answer (score 1):

If a compiler will know the body of the function then it can figure it out and will remove unnecessary jump. In fact, today's compilers are inlining most of the functions whenever they can, so you shouldn't probably worry about unnecessary jumps any more.

Comment: Any idea how Visual Studio 6 doe it?

Comment: "today's compilers" -- VS 6 is from 1998